# ionic2 creates no webpack.config.js

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, ionic2

I started a new ionic 2 project, but after that there is no webpack.config.js, where i could add source-map support, do I have to write the whole webpack.config.js on my own?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 6):

All ionic build settings are in app scripts module.
You can update your package.json to include your own webpack config like so:

```
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.json",
  },
```

For more details:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts